How to remove / forget a 2nd frame AND reuse it conditionally
Albeit having some coding experience, it was in 'old scole 3GL' like Cobol, but that was decades ago. Not to long ago, just for fun and out of curiosity, I looked into the 4GL object oriented aspects of Python (3.9.5) using the extensive info on the internet. After Writing some smaller code, started something bigger. Being a newbee at this, most likely I have some serious gaps in my 4GL / Python knowledge as I ran into an issue for which I cannot find a solution on web.
Goal:        The code requires for widges and frames to conditionally be switched on and of.
For the widgets part I found a workaround.
Problem:     For the frame part I keep getting
'AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'grid_remove'', regardless what I do.
Approach:    Included snippet I use to test remove/forget of both widgets and frames,
the former works fine, the later does not (see error).
The only thing I want it to do, is allow, conditionally, switch a frame On and Off.
Thanks for any constructive feedback.
Eric
PS Any advise on how to get a better understanding of what the actual contents is of the IMPORTs in Python, would be very much appreciated. Currently is a black box to me I just copy/past from code found on web to try figure out what it does by by trial and error. There has to be a more structured approach to this?
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root    = Tk()
root.title('root frame')
root.geometry('400x150+100+25')

# creating win1 as child (but is it?) from root/master. Used to test (un)hiding of frames
win1    = tk.Toplevel(root)
win1.title('win1 - to be (un)hide')
win1.geometry('400x150+700+25')

def but2():
    print('in BUT2 => Call REMOVE to kill Btn1')
    Label(win1, text='within BUT 2').grid()
    remove()

def but3():
    print('in BUT3 => that is to be removed')
    Label(win1, text='within BUT 3').grid()
    btn3 = Button(root, text ="BUT 3: will destroy root frame", command = root.destroy)
    btn3.grid()

def remove():
    print('in REMOVE => to try do remove BUT 1')
    btn1.grid_remove()
    Label(win1, text='within remove BUT 1').grid()
    #causes: AttributeError: 'Toplevel' object has no attribute 'grid_remove' => it exists as indicated with label?
    win1.grid_remove()

def revive():
    print('in REVIVE => to try revive BUT 1')
    btn1.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)
    Label(win1, text='within revive BUT 1').grid()
    win1.grid()

def kill_root():
    print('in KILL_ROOT => destroy root frame')
    root.destroy()

btn1 = Button(root, text ="BUT 1: this will destroy ROOT", command = kill_root)
btn1.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)
# create and hide it directly (works fine)
btn1.grid_remove()

btn2 = Button(root, text ="BUT 2: will remove BUT 1 + frame Win1", command = but2)
btn2.grid(row = 3, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)

btn3 = Button(root, text ="BUT 3: will revive BUT 1 + frame Win1", command = revive)
btn3.grid(row = 5, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)

# use label to instantiate (if that is the right terminology) win1
Label(win1, text='a label in Win1').grid()

mainloop()


As for the side question about imports: never use * imports and you'll have a much better time.

Found a way to SEE what 'from tkinter import something', does.
If I understand correctly:
Frame:
adds:       grid_forget, grid_remove
but no:     geometry, title
also:       any output will be shown in this one frame regardless of the child
Toplevel:
adds:       geometry, title
but no:     grid_forget, grid_remove
also:       allows for multiple frames BUT does not support forget/remove
LabelFrame:         is not a real frame, more a box drawn around some widgets
Beggs the question, is it possible in Python to use multiple frames that can be (un)hide at will?
